# php compare value if not

Tags: php

there have two value, `$a` and `$b`. I need make a judge, `$a` is not 3 times as bigger as b or `$b` is not 3 times as bigger as `$a`, `echo $a.'&nbsp;and&nbsp;'.$b;` else not.

for explain:

if `$a` = 5, `$b`=1 so `$b`*3 = 3,   `$b`*3 < `$a`, then echo 'nothing';

if `$a` = 5, `$b`=2 so `$b`*3 = 6,   `$b`*3 > `$a`, then echo `$a.'&nbsp;and&nbsp;'.$b;//5 and 6`

if `$b` = 5, `$a`=1 so `$a`*3 = 3,  `$a`*3 < `$b`, then echo 'nothing';

if `$b` = 5, `$a`=2 so `$a`*3 = 6,  `$a`*3 > `$b`, then echo `$a.'&nbsp;and&nbsp;'.$b;//6 and 5`

one of my code:

```
$a='5';
$b='1';
if ((!($a>=($b*3))) or (!($b>=($a*3)))){
    echo $a.'&nbsp;and&nbsp;'.$b; //this may be echo 'nothing'
}else{
  echo 'nothing';
}
```

Comment: im not sure what the question is....

Comment: @Neal, for my poor english, so i wrote some `for explain`, but still can not understood by others. How poor am I! I will try to write clearly, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for anyone, too many well answer, but I choose a simple one.

Comment: Your requirements are inconsistent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your examples, you seem to want to print 'nothing' if the values are very different, but if the values are close (within a factor of 3) then you print the values.

You just need to fix the logic in your test line:

if ($a < $b * 3  &&  $b < $a * 3) {

Comment: Thanks for anyone, too many well answer, but I choose a simple one.

Answer (score 3):

Replace `$a[0]`, `$a[1]`, `$b[0]`, and `$b[1]` with  `$a`, `$a`, `$b`, and `$b`, respectively.

Comment: I have modified, still echo '5 and 1' but as I need, `b*3` is not bigger than `a`, should echo `nothing`, if `b=2`,`a=5`, `b*3>a` then echo `5 and 2`.

Answer (score 1):

is this what you are asking?

function checkAandB($a, $b)
{
if($a==0 || $b==0)
return true; 
else if ($a/$b>=3 || $b/$a>=3)
return true;
else
return false
}

Answer (score 1):

```
//if $a = 5, $b=1 so $b*3 = 3, is still smaller than $a, then echo 'nothing';
if ($a > $b) && ($a > $b*3) { echo 'nothing'; }

//if $a = 5, $b=2 so $b*3 = 6, is bigger than $a, then echo $a.'&nbsp;and&nbsp;'.$b;//5 and 6
if ($a > $b) && ($a < $b*3) { echo $a . ' and ' . $b; }

//if $b = 5, $a=1 so $a*3 = 3, is still smaller than $b, then echo 'nothing';
if ($b > $a) && ($b > $a*3) { echo 'nothing'; }

//if $b = 5, $a=2 so $a*3 = 6, is bigger than $b, then echo $a.'&nbsp;and&nbsp;'.$b;//6 and 5
if ($b > $a) && ($b < $a*3) { echo $a . ' and ' . $b; }
```

What if $a==$b?

Answer (score 1):

I would make it much simpler than that. I like to always follow KISS.
If a person needs more than 5 seconds to read and to understand my line I would scrap it.

I would make a quick check which is smaller or bigger, then check if they are 3 times bigger or not.Maybe not as "efficient" as yours. but meh :).

```
function checkAandB($a,$b){
    if $a >= $b             //I assumed that if equal then it doesn't matter
         $smaller = $b;
         $bigger = $a
     else
         $smaller = $a;     //fixed a typo in here
         $bigger = $b;
    if $smaller < (3 * $bigger )
         do nothing
    else 
        echo $a and $b
```

It's pseudocode :) converted to your suitable language.

Answer (score 0):

```
function compareAB($a, $b) {
  return ($a < ($b * 3)) && ($b < ($a * 3)) ? "$a and $b" : "nothing";
  }

echo compareAB(5,1); // nothing
echo compareAB(5,2); // 5 and 2
```